# Node behind OpenWRT firewall

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, node.js, openwrt

I'm remote from my home server (OpenSuse 15.1), which contains a DB that I need to access. For reasons I don't want to go into here, I want to run a Node.js application co-located on the same machine. I have an OpenWRT router with the following port forward rule:

```
config redirect                              
        option target 'DNAT'                    
        option src 'wan'                        
        option dest 'lan'                    
        option proto 'tcp'                      
        option src_dport '3000'                 
        option dest_ip '192.168.7.7'         
        option name 'NodeTranq-0'               
        option dest_port '3000'
```

I restart the firewall with `/etc/init.d/firewall reload`
I edit the app via ssh and save the edits. I then run the app, which announces that it's running a webserver on port 3000. I then try my static WAN address and port 3000 from my remote machine (on Firefox 68.1.0esr (64-bit)) and I'd expect the URL to be picked up by my Node application. My Node application is app.js and contains:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I've not yet checked for any other firewall but will do (I don't think there is one). The connection is refused

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at <server ip>:3000.
```

Any other thoughts about what to try?

Comment: Do you try the WAN address _from inside the LAN_ or from outside? (This is a very common problem, search for "NAT hairpin" or "NAT loopback".) Does the computer receive _any_ of the incoming connection packets? (Use tcpdump or Wireshark as a packet capture tool.)

Comment: Outside the LAN - The http request is made remotely and I'm invoking the Node application via ssh, so locally - in a directory in my `/home/...` dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know much about node.js configuration, according to your setup, your application is listening only on `127.0.0.1` which is for loopback access only: only from the server to itself. So your application can't be accessed from remote, including from the LAN.

You should change your node.js configuration and put:

```
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
```

This is the [INADDR_ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508685/understanding-inaddr-any-for-socket-programming/16510000#16510000) address meaning the application will now listen on all interfaces and will accept a connection to any address it has, including the DNATed traffic to `192.168.7.7` and still including `127.0.0.1` for any local application configured to access it locally like before.

Comment: Huh, somehow I completely overlooked that.